# Access to the path is denied when save with filedialog

Tags: c#, xml, file-io, io

I have two forms of saving to a file:

One. I keep the path in the code.

Two. I get the path from the user.

When I save the path in the code, save successful. When I get from the user (the same path that I kept in the code) this fall with the following error:

```
Access to the path is denied
```

Here my save function (both ways come to the same function):

```
public void SaveFile(string path)
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyClass>));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, MyList);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

From the user I send to this function as follows:

```
public void UserSave()
{
    //Open dialog in the path that i have in the code:
    fileDialog.InitialDirectory = MyPath;
    if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        SaveFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDialog.FileName));
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: To quickly debug, you should first give the "everyone" permission to the directory where you are trying to save file. If that works, you can set the required permissions later.

Comment: Does MyPath refers to a folder or a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error in the following line:

```
SaveFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDialog.FileName));
```

It basically saves it as a **folder** instead of as a **file**, so it fell.

I changed it to this:

```
SaveFile(fileDialog.FileName);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same issue. I was doing Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)  and needed to add a file name after the folder path.